# Why Cassandra respond slowly on fetching data than splitting to different range queries?

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, cql

I'm designing a cassandra columnfamily as given below

```
CREATE TABLE PLOT  
(  
PLOT_ID text,  
INDEX_VALUE double,  
VALUE_1 double,  
VALUE_2 double,  
VALUE_3 double,  
PRIMARY KEY(PLOT_ID,INDEX_VALUE));
```

The design is so that i can query in a range of INDEX_VALUE also.
I'm expecting maximum number of **PLOT_ID** in table **PLOT** is 2700000.
**INDEX_VALUE** will be in {0-30000} for each PLOT_ID.

Most of the case, i need all data related to a PLOT_ID at once.
So i'm using a query like this.

```
SELECT INDEX_VALUE,VALUE_1,VALUE_2,VALUE_3 FROM PLOT WHERE PLOT_ID='p01';
```

But its taking some much time.
So i split query like as given below.

```
SELECT INDEX_VALUE,VALUE_1,VALUE_2,VALUE_3 FROM PLOT WHERE PLOT_ID='p01' and INDEX_VALUE <=1000 and INDEX_VALUE >=0;
SELECT INDEX_VALUE,VALUE_1,VALUE_2,VALUE_3 FROM PLOT WHERE PLOT_ID='p01' and INDEX_VALUE <=2000 and INDEX_VALUE >=1001;
....
....
....
SELECT INDEX_VALUE,VALUE_1,VALUE_2,VALUE_3 WHERE PLOT_ID='p01' and INDEX_VALUE <=30000 and INDEX_VALUE >=29001;
```

and its response a pretty faster.
What may be the issue?
My cassandra has only one node.
Is this due to cassandra configuration?
Any suggestions on my design?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration is not a factor, but the way Cassandra works. Using the default Murmur3Partitioner (recommended), querying by PLOT_ID partition key, which is a compound primary key, is retrieving all rows stored by (PLOT_ID INDEX_VALUE). When you include the INDEX_VALUE in the query, Cassandra retrieves less data, so I think this explains why it doesn't take so long for the query. Over the past few years, due to improvements such as clustering columns, which your compound primary key uses, Cassandra no longer iterates over all columns of given row to check which column matches a range. Data is stored contiguously based on clustering columns and can be retrieved efficiently.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your answer, but still don't get it.  Having `where PLOT_ID = 12` clause just on partition key it should simply return all data from this row, isn't it? As I understand it, adding a range on `INDEX_VALUE` should make the query slower, because it's needed to iterate over all columns of given row and check which column match range.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Hope this edit improves the explanation.

Comment: The combination of the PLOT_ID and INDEX_VALUE in the table uniquely identifies a row.

Comment: Still I'm having doubts :-) . Could you look [here](http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/) ? There's an analogy to Java `Map<RowKey, SortedMap<ColumnKey, ColumnValue>>`, so that rows are stored within map and clustering column is `SortedMap<ColumnKey, ColumnValue>`. Having such, it still sounds reasonable to me that I can get all data for any given RowKey (`PLOT_ID` in this case) and it would be more efficient than splitting a query into smaller range queries.

Comment: There is probably a more efficient way to model your query to get what you want, but the eBay blog is outdated. Super columns are no longer used. In Spring 2012 (http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cql-3-0), the first of major changes were announced. One of the big differences in CQL 3.0 from previous CQL versions was that WHERE clauses can include greater-than/less-than comparisons on columns other than the first. http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_intro_c.html is a better source of info if you're using a modern version of Cassandra.

Comment: I still don't feel it, but thank you four your patience. ps. this is not my question:-)

Comment: Will this be better?
`CREATE TABLE PLOT  
(  
PLOT_ID text,  
BUCKET_ID int,
INDEX_VALUE double,  
VALUE_1 double,  
VALUE_2 double,  
VALUE_3 double,  
PRIMARY KEY(PLOT_ID,BUCKET_ID,INDEX_VALUE));`

where `BUCKET_ID = INDEX_VALUE/1000.`
and query 
`SELECT * from PLOT WHERE PLOT_ID='p01' and BUCKET_ID=0` for getting INDEX_VALUE 0 to 999
`SELECT * from PLOT WHERE PLOT_ID='p01' and BUCKET_ID=1` for getting INDEX_VALUE 1000 to 1999
so on..

Comment: I asked for two opinions from guys who work on Cassandra queries. If there's any performance difference in querying the data in one model vs the other, the difference would be subtle. You would need to do benchmark testing to really answer the question. The first way (using <= x >= y) seems like the query path might be more complex, and cause a performance hit, but maybe not. The second way involves storing more data. It's an interesting question.